# Is MongoDB-backed persistence still in Akka?

Tags: scala, mongodb, persistence, akka

I found some docs for mongodb persistence in Akka 1.0, but can't seem to find any mention of it in the 1.2 docs. Was it removed? I also can't find anything that says it was removed or deprecated.

If it is still in Akka, any links to relevant docs would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, they decided to remove it in Akka 1.1:  http://groups.google.com/group/akka-user/browse_thread/thread/8867fd5c9d64db4e

Comment: Use Casbah directly, it's awesome.

Comment: Casbah is a mongo scala client right? so it's still using mongo?